# Bogoliubov transformation, same eigenvalues

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics

I have been reading about the Bogoliubov transformation of creation and annihilation operators:
\begin{align}
b & = u\,a + v\,a^\dagger\\
b^\dagger & = u^*  a^\dagger+v^*a
\end{align}

where $a,a^\dagger$ are the original operators and $b,b^\dagger$ are the "new" creation and annihilation operators.

My question: Why does the transformation preserve the eigenvalues of a hamiltonian containing $a$ and $a^\dagger$? Is there an easy way to explain this? I have looked at similar question, but still don't get it...

Similar questions:

[Why must the Bogoliubov transform preserve anticommutation relations?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/346247/why-must-the-bogoliubov-transform-preserve-anticommutation-relations)

[Bogoliubov transformation is not unitary transformation, correct?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/268268/bogoliubov-transformation-is-not-unitary-transformation-correct)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why would it *change* the eigenvalues of the hamiltonian? It is exactly the same hamiltonian, you've just re-expressed it in a form which is easier to understand. When you simplify a hamiltonian in the form
\begin{align}
H
& = A\,  a^\dagger a + B \,  a^\dagger a^\dagger+ B^*a a + C
\\ & = \omega b^\dagger b
\end{align}
for some suitable values of the parameters $u,v$, and $\omega$, the second equals sign really is an equals sign, i.e. it is the very same operator, and the only thing that's changed is that now you have a clearer canonical form to assign it. And, since it's the same operator, acting in the same way on the same space, the eigenvalues simply cannot change.

Comment: Just one more question: The transformation is clearly a rotation in the space of anihilation and creation operators. Why must it be a rotation?

Comment: @Luka8281 It's *not* a rotation (for bosons), it's a symplectic transformation. The reasons for that are in the second link in your question.