# Is Bogoliubov transformation simply a basis transformation?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, ising-model

I encounter Bogoliubov transformation when I'm learning 1D transverse field Ising Model.But I think it's just a simple basis transformation, I don't understand why people give it a special name?

Comment: An important aspect is that it is a canonical transformation.

Answer (score 3):

Any invertible transformation can be understood as a change of basis, but that doesn’t make it trivial (at least from a conceptual point of view). Some such transformations are so broadly useful and important that the physics community has collectively decided to give them special names. Bogoliubov transformations are one example; Fourier transforms (both continuous and discrete) are another.

Comment: It looks like the Bogoliubov transformation [does not have to be unitary](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/268268/bogoliubov-transformation-is-not-unitary-transformation-correct).

Comment: @mavzolej Indeed, you’re right. I’ve edited my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

"*...it's just a simple basis transformation*" — yes and no. Note that in the multi-particle case (what we are usually interested in) the [Bogoliubov transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogoliubov_transformation#Single_bosonic_mode_example) is defined by its action on single-particle modes in a Fock state.

When we say "a transformation" we may refer to two slightly different things. For a particular basis in a Hilbert space, we can imagine a matrix acting on a basis state $|i\rangle$ as $A_{ij}|i\rangle$. In reality, however, we typically deal with *operators*, whose action on basis states is defined in a rather peculiar way. Once the action of an operator on states is specified, we can surely calculate its matrix $u_{ij}$, but it's just important to keep in mind that oftentimes we don't really think it terms of such matrices.

For example, if [second quantization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_quantization) is used, the basis vectors are the so-called [Fock states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fock_space), the (anti-)symmetrized tensor products of single-particle basis states. Various operators acting on Fock states are then typically defined in terms of creation/annihilation operators acting on individual modes. **While the action of an operator on a single mode may look simple, its action on Fock states, constituting the basis of the Hilbert space, is actually quite non-trivial.**

So the beauty of the Bogoliubov transformation is in that, while being defined at the level of single-particle operators, it ends up being highly useful when studying the multi-particle system. However, the complexities described above don't bother us that much, as we do most things at the level of the Hamiltonian operator — substitute the new operators instead of the old ones, and then directly solve it in the new basis (i.e. a basis of new Fock states defined in terms of new single-particle states).