# Imaginary oscillation frequencies of quadratic bosonic Hamiltonians

Tags: quantum-mechanics, eigenvalue, second-quantization

Consider the Hamiltonian

\begin{equation}
    H = a^\dagger a + c^\dagger c + \text{i} \xi \left( a^\dagger - a \right) \left( c + c^\dagger \right),
\end{equation}

where $a$ and $c$ are bosonic annihilation operators obeying $[a,a^\dagger]=1$, $[c,c^\dagger]=1$ and $[a,c^\dagger]=0$, and $\xi>0$. The normal mode operator can be found by means of a Bogoliubov transformation, generically written as $\beta = \boldsymbol{\Gamma} \cdot \boldsymbol{\psi}$, where $\boldsymbol{\Gamma} = \left( a, c, a^\dagger, c^\dagger \right)$ and $\boldsymbol{\psi}$ is a vector of coefficients. The normal mode operator obeys the Heisenberg equation of motion $[\beta,H] = \omega \beta$. This leads to the matrix equation $\mathbf{M} \boldsymbol{\psi} = \omega \boldsymbol{\psi}$ where the Hopfield matrix [[1]](https://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.112.1555) is

\begin{equation}
    \mathbf{M} = \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & -\text{i} \xi & 0 & \text{i} \xi \\
    \text{i} \xi & 1 & \text{i} \xi & 0 \\
    0 & \text{i} \xi & -1 & -\text{i} \xi \\
    \text{i} \xi & 0 & \text{i} \xi & -1\\
    \end{pmatrix}.
\end{equation}

The eigenvalues are obtained from the equation $\text{det}(\mathbf{M}-\omega)=0$, giving

\begin{equation}
    \omega = \sqrt{1 \pm 2\xi}.
\end{equation}

Thus, for $\xi>1/2$ the Hamiltonian gives an imaginary frequency. I don't understand what it means to have an imaginary oscillation frequency. How is this possible? What does it mean? What is the physical intuition? Any further reading appreciated. The physical system I am interested in, is polaritons that arise due to strong light-matter coupling, where this method is used to calculate the dispersion of polaritons. So I find the possibility of an imaginary dispersion very puzzling.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115920/discussion-on-question-by-tom-imaginary-oscillation-frequencies-of-quadratic-bos).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you are you are seeking do find the frequencies of the *oscillation modes* and not the energy eigenvalues of some system. You  then plan to use a Bogoliubov transfoamtion to find the mode ladder opertors? If my guess  is correct, then you must realize that not all nice-looking quadratic bosonic systems have real eigenfrequancies.
If you have a pair of coupled harmonic oscillators
$$
H= p_1^2+p_2^2 + x_1^2+x^2_2 +2\lambda x_1 x_2  
$$  the potential term
$$
V(x_1,x_2)=[x_1,x_2]\left[\matrix{1&\lambda \cr \lambda & 1}\right]\left[\matrix{x_1 \cr x_2}\right]
$$
will have a negative eigenvalue if $\lambda^2>1$, and so the potential curves downward in one direction -- i.e it is unstable and the oscillation frequencies are imaginary.

If you re-express this  hamiltonian  in terms of the ladder operators  $a_1$ $a_1^\dagger$, $a_2$, $a^\dagger_2$ of the uncoupled oscillators   it have the same form as your hamiltonian, and will still be hermitian, but there will be complex mode frequencies.

So, unlike the fermionic case, not every hermitian Bose hamiltonian of the form
$$
\hat H = a^\dagger _i h_{ij}  a_j +\frac 12 a^\dagger _i \Delta_{ij} a^\dagger_j +\frac 12 a_i \Delta^*_{ij}a_j,
$$
is bounded below and can be solved by a Bogoliubov transformation.  The necessary condition is that the real symmetric matrix
$$
 \left[\matrix{ \Re(h+\Delta)_{ij}&\Im (\Delta-h)_{ij} \cr \Im(\Delta+h)_{ij}   & \Re(h-\Delta)_{ij}}\right],
$$
be positive definite. If so it can be diagonalized (Williamson's theorem) by conjugation by a real symplectic matrix. We need symplectic to preserve the Bose commutation relations.

Comment: Ah yes this is exactly the kind of information I was looking for, thanks very much for deciphering my question. Do you have any recommendations about where I read and understand more what it means to have imaginary oscillation frequencies. It's very puzzling to me. Physically I am interested in the dispersion of polaritons calculated in this manner, and it seems very unintuitive to me that the dispersion can become imaginary from a Hermitian Hamiltonian. Thanks

Comment: Related question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/53158/validity-of-bogoliubov-transformation

Comment: Also does this mean there is a difference between the *eigenvalues* of $H$, and the "oscillation frequencies" of $H$ obtained as above. If so, what are the differences? And how would I calculate the eigenfrequencies of $H$? And what would they physically correspond to, in contrast to the oscillation frequencies?

Comment: You could try to make Bogoliubov to write $H= \omega a^\dagger a$ with $\omega$ imaginary, but since the energy is not bounded below there is no state $|gnd\rangle$ such that $a|gnd\rangle=0$ so the imaginary $\omega$ does not lead to imaginary energies.  Bosons Bolgoliubov's are elements of the symplectic group, while Fermionic Bogoliubovs are elements of the orthogonal group. Being able to conjugate asymplectic group  element into the maximal torus  (i.e do a Bogoliubov)  is governed by Williamson's theorem on the symplectic diagonalization of positive definite real symmetric matrices.

Comment: https://www.math.arizona.edu/~rsims/ma541/Seye_lec.pdf  is a reference connecting  Williamson to oscillators. Sadly he does not mention Bogoliubov, but other refs that do, for example arXiv:1608.03289, are hard going for physicists.

Comment: Here https://www-m5.ma.tum.de/foswiki/pub/M5/Allgemeines/MacroscopicLimitsWorkshop/napiorkowski.pdf is another useful reference.

Answer (score -1):

The matrix $M$ is not Hermitian for real values of $\xi$. To see this, note that the upper-right and bottom-left elements are both $i\xi$. Conjugating and transposing only negates these elements, so $M^\dagger\not= M$. There are other elements for which the same thing happens, but pointing out one is sufficient to establish non-Hermeticity.

Comment: Thanks :) I know $\mathbf{M}$ is not a Hermitian matrix, but that is not my main concern. Please see discussion in comments on original question.

Comment: @Tom Any relevant information for the question should be in the question. Comments are not intended to be permanent, so referring users to comments is not useful. Please edit the question so it has all the information it needs.

Answer (score -1):

Your M matrix is not a Hermitian operator. This is obvious to check, $M^\ast\neq M$. for example, you can see ${M_{14}}^\ast\neq M_{41}$.

Comment: Thanks :) I know $\mathbf{M}$ is not a Hermitian matrix, but that is not my main concern. Please see discussion in comments on original question.